# search sub list into another list in android

Tags: android, arrays

For example there are two lists(Array List) A and B . 
Length(size) of A is 10 and Length(size) is 100 .
 All the items of A exists in B. I want to get index position in B which is in A.

```
A[
    {
        id = 10, name = "a"
    },
    {
        id = 22, name = "b"
    },
    {
        id = 30, name = "c"
    },
    {
        id = 45, name = "d"
    },
    {
        id = 55, name = "e"
    },
    ...
]

B[
    {
        id = 1, name = "xx"
    },
    {
        id = 2, name = "yy"
    },
    ...
    {
        id = 10, name = "a"
    },
    {
        id = 11, name = "zz"
    },
    ...
    {
        id = 22, name = "b"
    },
    ...,
    {
        id = 100, name = "hello"
    }
]
```

I want to index position A item in B. I am using two for loops. But it is taking time.
If there are any way to search these items using one for loop or any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) to store the larger array of the two. This way, you only have to iterate through the smaller array, checking if the current object exists in the [hash map](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) in O(1), which gives you a total complexity of O(n), where n is the dimension of the smaller array.